# Gephi 0.9.0 partition panel

Tags: gephi

I've just started with Gephi using 0.9.0. When I go to the Overview window there is no Partition panel, or anything except the Appearance panel. All the help is based on 0.8.x and the UI seems to have gone through a major overhaul, so nothing online helps. How do I get to it?
Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 8):

The answer is in [this topic](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1258):

> Hi, in 0.9 ranking and partition modules have been merged into a single "Appearance" tab. The functionalities are the same and if you click on "Attribute" it should look like what ranking or partition looked like.

Answer (score 4):

You have a point there because in the original 0.9 release, this was an issue. Make sure you install all the updates first, from **Tools>Plugins** and hit **Check for updates**.

Next time you would want to partition your graph, make sure you choose a categorical attribute to do so. Then click on the black palette icon that is used to color nodes and select **Attribute**. Check, Clement Levallois' [excellent tutorial](http://www.clementlevallois.net/gephi/tuto/en/gephi_tutorial%20foundations_en.pdf), slide 25 in the pdf, for more details

Comment: That link to the 'excellent tutorial' is broken, unfortunately. Try his repository at: https://seinecle.github.io/gephi-tutorials/